# custom font and font-smooth

Tags: html, css

I tried add custom font and have lots of troubles :(
this is my test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        @font-face {
        font-family: 'OpenSans';
        src: url('OpenSans.eot');
        src: url('OpenSans.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
            url('OpenSans.woff') format('woff'),
            url('OpenSans.ttf') format('truetype');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
    body {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: 'OpenSans';
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <span>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry<span>
</body>
</html>
```

I result I have (Windows XP SP3 ClearType disable):

[image: 22]

I don't know why my opera doesn't want to read this font from local directory. Safari and Chrome didn't enable font-smooth (how I understand it depend on OS and I can't fix it without change OS settings).

2 Question:

1) Why doesn't opera understand local path (if it's deploy on http server it will be work)?

2) How to enable font-smooth for chrome and safari? Firefox does it without trouble and maybe it's possible for other browser (css property font-smooth doesn't help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't explain the Opera issue but the cleartype issue seems straight-forward. IE and Firefox are ignoring your system preference for disabled cleartype and chrome and safari are doing what you asked and honouring it.

Here's how I read the issue. YOU (the user) have expressly told the system not to use cleartype. MS decides to ignore that choice in IE which gives you the impression that IE does awesomer rendering than other browsers. Mozilla cops a lot of shit from users with CT disabled who think IE fonts look better so they bow to pressure and ignore your choice as well. Apple are happy for things to look worse on Windows than Macs so they do nothing. Chrome decides to take the high-ground and honours the users choice. Alternatively I could be making all that up.

The reasons aren't important, the point is that when you disable CT then it should be disabled. What you are actually asking is how to make a website ignore the users system preferences and the simple answer is - you can't, and you shouldn't. Like many things in the web browser wars some browsers are doing the right thing and some browsers are not and there's nothing you can do about it.